# How to create IAM role access against s3 bucket deny policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

I have s3 bucket with bucket policy which deny's all the actions. i wanted to create IAM role to list, put, get object actions. How can i achieve that.

**s3-bucket-policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "denyInsecureTransport",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

i have created IAM policy to perform actions against this bucket.

**IAM Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

with this i am getting **access denied** error. how to modify this policy to perform s3 bucket actions. any help would be appreciated.

**EDITED**

module block:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "bucket_public_access" {
  count  = var.create ? 1 : 0
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket[0].bucket
  block_public_acls   = true
  block_public_policy = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy" {
  count  = var.create ? 1 : 0
  bucket = local.bucket_name
  #policy = templatefile(var.bucket_policy_template, { account_number = var.account_number, region = var.region, bucket_name = local.bucket_name })

  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_comb_policy[0].json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy" {
  count = var.create ? 1 : 0
  statement {
    sid    = "denyInsecureTransport"
    effect = "Deny"

    actions = [
      "s3:*",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${local.bucket_name}",
      "arn:aws:s3:::${local.bucket_name}/*"


    ]
    principals {
      type        = "*"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "Bool"
      variable = "aws:SecureTransport"
      values = [
        "false"
      ]
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket[0],
  ]

}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "object_lock_policy" {
  count = var.create && var.object_lock ? 1 : 0
  statement {
    sid    = "ObjectLockConfiguration"
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [
      "s3:BypassGovernanceRetention",
            "s3:PutBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
            "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
            "s3:PutObjectRetention"
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${local.bucket_name}",
      "arn:aws:s3:::${local.bucket_name}/*"
    ]
    principals {
      type        = "*"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "ArnNotEquals"
      variable = "aws:PrincipalArn"
      values = [
        "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_number}:role/${var.department}-jenkins-assumed-role-${var.environment}"
      ]
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket[0],
  ]
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_comb_policy" {
  count = var.create ? 1 : 0

  source_policy_documents = compact([
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy[0].json,
    var.object_lock ? data.aws_iam_policy_document.object_lock_policy[0].json : "",
    var.additional_policy != null ? var.additional_policy : ""
  ])
}
```

and also they created one IAM role in the module itself

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "replication_role" {
  count              = var.create && length(var.replication_bucket_arn) != 0 ? 1 : 0
  name               = "${local.bucket_name}-s3-replication-role"
  permissions_boundary = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_number}:policy/AGT-IAM-BOUNDARY-BASE"
  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "s3ReplicationAssume"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "replication_policy" {
  count  = var.create && length(var.replication_bucket_arn) != 0 ? 1 : 0
  name   = "${local.bucket_name}-s3-replication-policy"
  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket[0].arn}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
         "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
         "s3:GetObjectVersion"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket[0].arn}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ReplicateObject",
        "s3:ReplicateDelete",
        "s3:ReplicateTags"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "${var.replication_bucket_arn}/*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "replication_policy_attachment" {
  count      = var.create && length(var.replication_bucket_arn) != 0 ? 1 : 0
  role       = aws_iam_role.replication_role[0].name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.replication_policy[0].arn
}
```

Comment: Its not possible. `Deny` **always wins**. You have to change your bucket policy.

Comment: @Marcin i have used central module to create s3 bucket. i cannot change that centrally. is there any way to change that. i edited the module policy in this question. can you pls suggest any.

Comment: "access denied error" - what exactly do you do that you get the errors? use AWS CLI, console, ...?

Comment: i am trying to add s3 trigger to lambda function. and getting this error. i am running terraform apply through jenkins job

Comment: @Marcin in module level they attached one role. i added that in the question also

Comment: The bucket policy deny is only when the end user is not using secured connection or HTTPS to do the S3 operations.  Can you add the s3 bucket arn and s3 bucket arn/* to both the resources. I see the List is only given at the s3 arn.